# Iterating over a List of Strings In Java?

Tags: java, list, csv, iterator

I am using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read data from a CSV file and am using some of the sample code from the homepage:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("stockInfo.csv"));
List myEntries = reader.readAll();
```

And i am now trying to loop through this list and print out each entry. But i cannot seem to figure out the code to perform this.

Could anyone explain to me how i am supposed to do this becuase i just cant seem to work it out.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to output each entry of each line to it's own line:

```
    List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
    for (String[] lineTokens : myEntries) {
        for (String token : lineTokens) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Can't you do:
1)

```
for(int i = 0; i < myEntries.size(); i++){
  myEntries.get(i); // do something else here
}
```

or

2)

```
for(String s: myEntries)
   // Do work on s here
```

Comment: Read the doc (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/api/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html), yo. It's a list of arrays of Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an Iterator?
It should be something like this:

```
Iterator it = myEntries.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using generics with `CSVReader` if possible. `readAll()` actually returns a `List<String[]>` and not a `List<String>`. Then, you just need to:

```
for (String[] row : myEntries) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something of this effect. I've added synchronization on iterator.

```
List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
Iterator<String[]> iter = myEntries.iterator();
synchronized (iter) {
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String[] items = iter.next();

        for (String item: items) { //foreach loop
            //Work with `item`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `synchronized` is useless because `iterator()` will return a new `Iterator` instance. So you're synchronizing on local variable that's not shared with any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 and above you can also do

```
    List<String> s = new LinkedList<>();
    s.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
```

or

```
    List<String> s = new LinkedList<>();
    s.stream().forEach(s ->
            System.out.print(s)
    );
```

It is possible to use paralleStream() instead or stream() to make parallel execution. There are a lot of articles on the internet about which will execute quicker and the answer is : "it depends" (mostly on the number of items in the list)